# JSON to C# : convert an arraylist of doubles to an array of ints?

Tags: c#, arraylist, double, int

I have an arraylist of doubles returned by a JSON library. After the JSON parser's decode method is run, we have this in the C# locals window:

```
Name     Value           Type
myObj    Count=4         object {System.Collections.ArrayList}
[0]      100.0           object {double}
[1]      244.0           object {double}
[2]      123.0           object {double}
[3]      999.0           object {double}
```

My goal is to produce an array of integers from this ArrayList. It would be simple to iterate and do this one value at a time, but I'd like to know how to do it using the built-in converter functionality.  I have been reading theads on ConvertAll but I cannot get it to work.

I do not have control of the JSON library so I must begin with the ArrayList.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with `ArrayList`s because of boxing. Thus:

```
// list is ArrayList      
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(list.ToArray(), o => (int)(double)o);
```

Note the cast is framed as `(int)(double)`. This first unboxes the boxed `double` and then casts to an `int`.

To do this in older versions of .NET

```
// list is ArrayList
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(
    list.ToArray(),
    delegate(object o) { return (int)(double)o; }
);
```

An alternative is

```
// list is ArrayList
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(
    (double[])list.ToArray(typeof(double)),
    o => (int)o
);
```

Here we do not need an unboxing operation because we have first converted the `ArrayList` to an array of unboxed `double`s.

To do this in older versions of .NET

```
// list is ArrayList
int[] array = Array.ConvertAll(
    (double[])list.ToArray(typeof(double)),
    delegate(double o) { return (int)o; }
);
```

Comment: Jason thanks for the boxing caveats. I am very new to C#. What is the "=>" operator? VS2005 rejects it an 'Invalid expression term'.

Comment: The `=>` is the lambda operator and `o => (int)(double)o` is an example of a lambda expression. It's basically a very special anonymous delegate. It's a feature that was added in C# 3.5. I'll edit my post to show you how to do the above in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: Thanks again for this explanation, Jason, and my thanks to everyone else who replied showing a variety of ways to do this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Linq:

```
var array = (from double d in list
             select (int)d).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think something like this (with converter):

```
    private void Main()
    {
        List<Double> lstd = new List<Double>();

        lstd.Add(100.0);
        lstd.Add(244.0);
        lstd.Add(123.0);
        lstd.Add(999.0);

        List<int> lsti = lstd.ConvertAll(new Converter<double, int>(DoubleToInt));

    }


    public static int DoubleToInt(double dbl)
    {
        return (int)dbl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sample of a working solution using ConvertAll, here's a quick snippet.

```
 public static void testCOnvertAll()
        {
            List<double> target = new List<double>();
            target.Add(2.3);
            target.Add(2.4);
            target.Add(3.2);

            List<int> result = target.ConvertAll<int>(new Converter<double, int>(DoubleToInt));

        }

        public static int DoubleToInt(double toConvert)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(toConvert);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The linq options are cleaner, but if you don't have linq.

```
//Assuming someValues is your input array and you're sure you don't need to check the types
int[] outputValues = new int[someValues.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < someValues.Count; i++)
   outputValues[i] = (int)someValues[i];
```